# Iterator of map STL C++ it doens't work?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have strange problem. I declareded iterator of map::iterator but it doesn't work. Where is problem?

```
 string name "John";
    int count = 200;
    map<string,int> store;
    map<string,int>::iterator it;

it = store.find( name );

            if ( it != store.end() )
            {
                it->second += count;
            } else
            {
                store.insert( make_pair (name, count) );
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I can't use interator it. I want find name John in map. If there isn't John then I insert. If there is John then I only plus count.

Comment: It is not clear from your question, if by not working you mean it does not compile; it compiles with warnings; compiles, but the program freezes; the program crashes; `find` method incorrectly claims it did not find; it incorrectly claims it did find; it finds, but returns an iterator to a different element; it finds the correct element, but corrupts the stack; it creates temp files in the current directory which it shouldn't etc.

Comment: This problem when I compile: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = ((std::map<std::string, int, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, int> > >*)this)->std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key = std::string, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::string>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, int> >](((const std::string&)((const std::string*)(&name))))'

Comment: It works, [_Live Code_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4721aa33ca2fcaad98c34232ea61c3ed-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote should work on an updated C++ compiler.

I think you forget to include `<map>` to the code. See this [*Live Code*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4721aa33ca2fcaad98c34232ea61c3ed-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "John";
    int count = 200;
    map<string, int> store;
    map<string, int>::iterator it;

    it = store.find(name);

    if (it != store.end())
    {
        it->second += count;
    }
    else
    {
        store.insert(make_pair(name, count));
        cout << "ADDING NEW VALUE" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output

```
ADDING NEW VALUE
```

The method [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns an iterator and the code caught it fine and use it.

Comment: thank you. It was bad arguments in map<int,string>::iterator it;

Comment: @user1779502 bear in mind that you don't actually need all that code, unless you really need to perform an aciton of an element is not in the map.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you mean by "doesn't work", but you can greatly simplify your code:

```
store[name] += count;
```

Explanation: `store[name]` will add an entry if there isn't one there already, with a value constructed mapped value. In this case, since your mapped type is `int`, it will be zero initialized.